# "could not initialize proxy - no Session" For Multiple ManyToMany relationships in the parent

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a Parent User Class that has multiple ManyToMany Relationships.

```
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    ..
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH})
    @JoinTable(
        name =  "user_address",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")}
    )
    @JsonIgnore
    private final List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH})
    @JoinTable(
        name =  "reports",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "reports_id")}
    )

    @JsonIgnore
    private final List<Reports> reports = new ArrayList<Reports>();
}
```

When I access the FIRST ManyToMany property, everything works fine. However, immediately after
accessing the first, when I try to access the SECOND ManyToMany Property I get the "could not initialize proxy - no Session" exception:

```
@Component
public class Combiner {
    public void combineData() {
        ...
        List<Address> addresses = user.getAddress(); // This works
        List<Reports> reports = user.getReports();   // Get the error here
        ..
    }
}
```

The `Address` and `Reports` classes have the inverse relationship as many ManyToMany back to the `User` Entity Above.

```
public class Address {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "addresses", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private final List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
}

public class Reports {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "reports", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private final List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
}
```

I tried searching SO for the same error where there are MULTIPLE relationships like mine and the first passes but second fails, but could'nt find a post (or google couldn't understand the search terms, if anyone knows a pre-existing one - please let me know).
Could someone assess what else Im missing?

I've tried these so far to no avail:

- Added @Transactional to the parent Service class that calls `Combiner` above
- Made the second failing relationship `EAGER`. (as i understand it you cant make BOTH EAGER since i get a multiple bags error probably because of Cartesian join)

AM Using SpringBoot (2.2.4) with Hibernate Core {5.4.10.Final}

Comment: -- *The Address and Reports classes have the inverse relationship as many ManyToMany back to the User Entity Above.* - can you try removing this bidirectional relationship.

Comment: And also can you post the full exception to see why session get closed?

Comment: @ErfanAhmed isn't that a requirement for Many to Many?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai ```failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.foo.Address.users, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.foo.dto.UserDTO["addresses"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.foo.Address["users"])```

Comment: @DorianMcAllister `@ManyToMany` can be uni-directional. The exception clearly says it can not initialize the collection of `role` you have in `User` class.

Comment: Interesting that worked! @ErfanAhmed Could you respond in the Answer so I can mark it as Answered?  Also - Why cant this use case be Bi Directional?

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to use entities in serialization. Entities can be bidirectional and serialization (usually into hierarchical representations) is hardly able to do that "out of the box" - it's better to have a model for serialization and a model for entities and project one into the other.

Comment: @Smutje Can you please elaborate? I don't know what this means! What do you mean by "Entitiies"? What is "Model for Serialization" and "Project one into the other"?

Comment: @DorianMcAllister **Entities** are your *POJO*'s that you map to the database tables with `@Table` annotation. **Model** - is also a *POJO* that we usually create to store collective information together in a single `class` but not mapped to a database table. **Serialization** - the `class`es responsible to transfer data in between model and view are usually *[serialized](https://www.journaldev.com/2452/serialization-in-java)*.  **Project one into the other** - in a large project usually **Model**, **Service**, **Controller** and **view** files are kept in separate directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach one:**
Make `@ManyToMany` uni-directional. The exception clearly says it can not initialize the collection of `role` you have in `User` class.

As you asked in the comment section *Why can't this use case be Bi Directional* - You can make this `bi-directional` as well.
**Approach two:** make collection of `role` **EAGER** or use `Hibernate.initialize()` to initialize the collection.

**Bonus:** you can make both `collection` `EAGER` by using `Set` not `List`.